# Object prototype on a specific prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype

How do I extend an object type for ONLY a specific object type? I don't want conflicts with another library using object.color(). 
At the moment, I'm using:

```
function random_int(start,end) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(end-start+1)+start);
}
var balls = function balls (context) {
    this.canvas = context.canvas;
    this.context = context;
}
Object.prototype.ball = function ball() { }
balls.prototype.add = function () {
  this.context.fillStyle = '#ABC123';
  this.radius = 15;
  this.x = random_int(this.radius+1,this.canvas.width-this.radius-1);
  this.y = random_int(this.radius+1,this.canvas.height-this.radius-1);
  return this;
}
Object.prototype.draw = function () {
  this.context.beginPath();
  this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, (Math.PI/180)*360, false);
  this.context.fill();
  this.context.closePath();
}
balls.prototype.redraw = function () {
    this.context.save();
    this.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    this.context.restore();
    this.draw();
}
Object.prototype.color = function (col) {
    this.context.fillStyle = col;
}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth*0.9;
context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight*0.9;
var Balls = new balls(context);
for (var i = 0; i<10;i++) {
    var b = Balls.add();
    b.color("#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16));
    b.draw();
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hNy3r/1/

**Using two classes as I plan to loop through each of the balls in the Balls class later.**

Comment: Why would you need to extend basic `Object`? It's a base class for _everything_ in JS including strings, numbers, etc. So your code will become quite messy. Define your own `MyObject` (or something unique) and use it as a base for other stuff like Ball. It is also a good practice to put everything inside one big object creating a namespace analogue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ending up doing this:

```
function random_int(start, end) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start + 1) + start);
}
var balls = function balls(context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.add = function () {
        return new ball(context);
    }
}
Object.prototype.ball = function ball(context) {
                this.context = context;
                this.canvas = context.canvas;
    this.context.fillStyle = '#ABC123';
    this.radius = 15;
    this.x = random_int(this.radius + 1, this.canvas.width - this.radius - 1);
    this.y = random_int(this.radius + 1, this.canvas.height - this.radius - 1);
    this.draw = function () {
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, (Math.PI / 180) * 360, false);
        this.context.fill();
        this.context.closePath();
    }
    this.redraw = function () {
        this.context.save();
        this.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        this.context.restore();
        this.draw();
    }
    this.color = function (col) {
        this.context.fillStyle = col;
    }
    return this;
}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.9;
context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.9;
var Balls = new balls(context);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var b = Balls.add();
    b.color("#" + ((1 << 24) * Math.random() | 0).toString(16));
    b.draw();
}
```

Called `new ball()` from inside `balls`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want conflict why just not use the own scope why ever need to extend Object ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function random_int(start,end) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(end-start+1)+start);
    }
    var balls = function balls (context) {
        this.canvas = context.canvas;
        this.context = context;
    
    this.ball = function () { return this; }
    this.add = function () {
      this.context.fillStyle = '#ABC123';
      this.radius = 15;
      this.x = random_int(this.radius+1,this.canvas.width-this.radius-1);
      this.y = random_int(this.radius+1,this.canvas.height-this.radius-1);
      return this;
    }
    this.draw = function () {
      this.context.beginPath();
      this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, (Math.PI/180)*360, false);
      this.context.fill();
      this.context.closePath();
    }
    this.redraw = function () {
        this.context.save();
        this.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        this.context.restore();
        this.draw();
    }
    this.color = function (col) {
        this.context.fillStyle = col;
    }
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth*0.9;
    context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight*0.9;
    var Balls = new balls(context);
    for (var i = 0; i<10;i++) {
        var b = Balls.add();
        b.color("#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16));
        b.draw();
    }
});
```

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hNy3r/2/)

Comment: include something more to your sample, to see real problem, javascript have no classes btw and i really not suggest to extend Object

Comment: This is overriding the this, I need it to be seperate so I can have different b's if that makes sense

Comment: I not understand you, `this` is the private special variable, where i override it ? Add more code to your sample.

Comment: Your scope is wacko. I've solved it now, anyway. See my answer.

Comment: did you ever heard about private properties ?